# IWICImagingFactory decoder from memory

Tags: c++, windows

I am currently using the IWICImagingFactory api call CreateDecoderFromFilename which takes a file name to create a decoder.  However, I have the file already loaded into an array and want to use that.  Does anyone have any idea how to do that?  The API seems a tiny bit obscure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [`SHCreateMemStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831.aspx) to create an `IStream` interface to your memory buffer, then use [`IWICImagingFactory::CreateDecoderFromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690309.aspx) to create a decoder from that stream.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.  I found the CreateDecoderFromStream, but couldn't find how to create the stream.  Thanks.